# What is the Plant on This Star Trek Scene?

Tags: identification

I'm currently watching Star Trek: The Next Generation, and am curious about what the plants in those pots are. They appear at around minute 35 of the very first episode. The left might be some kind of maple, but I'm more interested in the right one. Unfortunately Google Lens didn't help.

Could you please help me identifying the right one?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: One plant per question please; see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whe for more information about this policy

Comment: @NiallC. Thanks for your comment. This is why I already specified that in my question. I'll make it more precise :)

Comment: Some variant on garden croton *Codiaeum variegatum*? There are lots of plants in the genus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croton_(plant)

Comment: @WayfaringStranger This looks really good. Tough I haven't found a picture of a plant that resembles this one, I have to admit that the picture isn't that good, and it might be a cut down plant.